# Proof accident (wheel related)

Tags: wheels, accident

like a student on forensics I study how we could detect some accident trace on a car who look like nice. I should find something related to wheels.
I think I have find already one.

After an accident, even if you fix what is visible the parallelism of the car could be still not correct. So it's my first proof of accident.

But I need to find 4 other proof of accident, related to the wheels of the car.

Have you some idea in mind ?

Comment: what about Fresh paint?

Comment: Yes of course is still something, even if I looking for issue more related to mecanic thing

Comment: One new wheel, three old (one replaced) hairline cracks, dents or evidence of dents being hit out, new lug nuts on only one wheel, new tire only on one wheel, etc?